# TYPO3 How to extend existing extensions table definition

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am supposed to extend a TYPO3 Extension that a colleague wrote who is not working with us any longer.

Say we have a collection of animals, like dogs, cats, birds, snakes whatever. Now I need to add a new relation that specifies the animals family, like mammal, bird, reptile.

I figured I have to do the following:

- Add a new class Family in Classes/Domain/Model/Family.php
- Add the new relation to Classes/Domain/Model/Animal.php
- Add the new fields to ext_typoscript_setup.txt
- Add a number of lines to ext_tables.php

Unfortunately, the table is not created in the database and does not appear in the backend. Can anyone please hint me to what I am missing? (If you believe I did something wrong, I am willing to share my code, right now I have the feeling there is just a step missing - like initializing the new data et.al.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a significant step:

In order to have the fields show up in the backoffice, one is required to add them to the TCA array and more specific to the interface sub-array like so:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_mytable']['interface']['showRecordFieldList'] .= ",newfield";
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_mytable']['feInterface']['fe_admin_fieldList'] .= ", newfield";
```

Hope this becomes useful to someone after all...

Answer (score 1):

Seems legit.

After you create/extend all this files, you should go into the install-tool modul.
Log in and go in the "Important actions"-Area and run "Compare current database with specification".

You should probably see all your new tables and fields.
Select all queries and start them with"Execute"-button.

Let me know if this solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for that hint - I was missing this step. The tool compares the database with the ext_tables.sql file, so I added my CREATE TABLE in there. For another table that existed in the system I tried to go with a ALTER TABLE in the ext_tables first, but that did not work. I had to build a CREATE TABLE statement that included the extra field I needed. Unfortunately the add-in still does not care about the field, but I'll dig further into it.